# React, how to render static json data with different keys

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

Here's an example of the static json data.

I'm having trouble rendering the '***promoimage***' from the array.

I'm not 100% sure how to go about this to solve it.  I was playing arround and wanted to check if 'promoimage' exists, but nothing was returned?
Any advice how to achieve this?

```
[
    {
        "title": "some title",
        "promoimage": "image.jpg",
        "url": "#"
    },
    {
        "title": "some title",
        "image": "example.jpg",
        "url": "#"
    },
{
        "title": "some other title",
        "promoimage": "image.jpg",
        "url": "#"
    },
    {
        "title": "title",
        "image": "example.jpg",
        "url": "#"
    },
]
```

My React component:

```
import products from '../product-data.json';
...
export const CustomSlider = () => {
   // Here I'm using react-slick 

 const productList = products.map((product, i) => {
    const uniqueItems = [];
    if (uniqueItems.indexOf(product.imageone) === -1) {
        uniqueItems.push(product.imageone);
    }

   /* This works
     if (product.hasOwnProperty('promoimage')) {
      return true
    }
   */

         return <Product key={i} {...product} />;
        }
    );

  return (
      <Slider>
        {productList}
      </Slider>  
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is sending all object keys to `Product`, as props. Particularly this part `{...product}` is expanded into this:

```js
<Product 
  key={i}
  title="some title"
  promoimage="image.jpg"
  url="#"
/>
```

This is called spreading.

Now, I suspect `<Product>` doesn't know what to do with `promoimage`, but knows what to do with `image`. We haven't sent any `image` so we have to fix that. We can do so by either modifying product so that it renders `image || promoimage`, or change our parsing to this:

```
const productList = products.map((product, i) => {
  const uniqueItems = []

  if (uniqueItems.indexOf(product.promoimage) === -1) {
    uniqueItems.push(product.promoimage)
  }

  return (
    <Product
      key={i}
      {...product}
      image={product.image || product.promoimage}
    />
  )
})
```

Comment: Nice one, this works. I tried with something simple to check with hasOwnProperty, ```if (product.hasOwnProperty('promoimage')) {
      return true
    }```  and noticed that the last item disappeared. No idea why. I've added the code above. But I understand your solution. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to hear. You can also accept the reply as solution.